# Currently playing song in Banshee

Tags: python, banshee

I want to get currently playing song in banshee media player using python and then set the equalizer according to the genre of song.

I didn't find any python module for accessing Banshee or getting that information.
Can someone point me to a source or give me a method to get that data and do the required equalizer setting ?

Comment: Some controls for Banshee are available through DBus, which you can access using Python. However, it doesn't seem to expose selection of equalizer settings. http://banshee.fm/contribute/write-code/dbus-interfaces/ http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html

Comment: So is there any way of accomplishing the equalizer settings part?